# jquery ajax call using $_GET from link

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get my data from a query string, but use it with Ajax.
I cant seem to get the data passed correctly and I am wondering where my syntax is wrong:

```
$(function()
      {
    $("#link").click(function(event)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.get("request.php",{id:+link.attr('id')},function(response){

                $("#ajaxresponse div").fadeOut("fast", function()
                {
                    $("#ajaxresponse div").remove();
                    $("#ajaxresponse").append($(response).hide().fadeIn());
                });

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

The html page code:

```
<div class="content">

<a href="request.php?id=1" id="link">


</div>
```

Am I not structuring the data to the ajax call correctly??

Thanks in advance

I can get it to return properly, but not in Ajax fashion, it is still loading the .php page instead of appending it, here is the request.php side of things:

```
   $username = $_GET['id'];


 echo getTemplate($username);

 function getTemplate($username)
   {
return '<div class="box">
    <h1>ID is</h1>
    <div class="meta">username: '.$username.'</div>
</div>';

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this function outside any other function :

```
function getUrlVars(url){

    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

then use :

```
getUrlVars($(this).attr("href"))["id"]
```

instead of

```
link.attr('id')
```

**demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/zY9s2/

Comment: @Jjames i'm gald i could help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a utility function like this

```
function getParameterByName(name,url) {

    var match = RegExp('[?&]' + name + '=([^&]*)')
                    .exec(url);

    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

}
```

and then use it in your code use it like

```
$("#link").click(function(event)
    {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = getParameterByName('id',$(this).attr('href'));
        $.get("request.php",{id:id},function(response){
```

**Demo:**   http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/dPX2h/

Answer (score 0):

```
{id:+link.attr('id')}
```

should be

```
{ id: link.attr('id') }
```